# CurlUrlInvalidException : Facebook Real time update

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time, facebook-php-sdk

I was trying to implementing facebook real time update. It looks like i was able to subscribe.

```
  `$param = array(
            'access_token' => $user_access_token,
            'object' => 'user',
            'fields' => 'name',
            'callback_url' =>'http://127.0.0.1/storm/callback.php',
            'verify_token' => 'XYZ',
            'active' => true
            );
  $subs = $facebook->api('/'.$app_id.'/subscriptions', 'POST', $param);
```

`

I get this error:

`{"message":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/storm\/callback.php?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=1229793076&hub.verify_token=XYZ is an internal url, but this is an external request.","type":"CurlUrlInvalidException"}}`

Does this have anything to do with me testing it locally??
How can i fix this? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use your real ip address in 'callback_url'